# cvs command not found by a Python Mac app created using py2app

Tags: python, macos, wxpython, cvs, py2app

Some system/software info before getting started:

OS: Mac OS X 10.7.1

Python: Active Python 2.7.2.5

wxPython: wxPython2.9-osx-2.9.1.1-cocoa-py2.7

I have a small wxpython-based Mac app that just tests the availability of cvs and svn on a Mac platform. This is the python code on which the Mac app is based:

```
import wx
import commands,os

ID_RUN_BUTTON=1
class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
          wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=(100, 100),style=wx.MINIMIZE_BOX | wx.CLOSE_BOX)
          self.run_button=wx.Button(self,ID_RUN_BUTTON,label='Run')
          self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnRun,id=ID_RUN_BUTTON)
          self.Centre()
          self.Show()

    def OnRun(self,evt):
          home_dir=os.path.expanduser("~")
          a=commands.getoutput("cvs")
          b=commands.getoutput("svn help")
          f=open('%s/cvs_test' % (home_dir),'w')
          f.write(a)
          f.write('\n')
          f.write(b)
          f.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(redirect=False)
    frame = Frame(None, -1, 'CVS Tester')
    app.MainLoop()
```

Here is a screen shot of this simple GUI with one button called 'Run'.

[image: screen shot of the simple cvs test app with a single 'Run' button]

On pressing 'Run' it executes the OnRun method and it saves the output of the two commands 'cvs' and 'svn help' into a file called 'cvs_test' in the user's home directory. When I run this code using the python interpreter on command-line, the output of both the commands is spit into a text file. Both cvs and svn commands are recognized and the output in the file cvs_test is as expected.

Now the problem is when I create a Mac app using py2app with the following script:

```
"""
This is a setup.py script generated by py2applet

Usage:
    python setup.py py2app
"""

from setuptools import setup

APP = ['cvs_test.py']
DATA_FILES = [('icons',['./icons/ark-2.png'])]
OPTIONS = {'iconfile': './icons/ark-2.icns'}

setup(app=APP,data_files=DATA_FILES,options={'py2app': OPTIONS},setup_requires=['py2app'])
```

The Mac app is created absolutely fine. But, when I open the Mac app and hit the 'Run' button, in the cvs_test file it created, it says:

"**sh: cvs: command not found**"

The Mac app is obviously running the same script but it couldn't find the cvs command.

In my home directory, the following are the contents of my .profile file:

```
export TERM="xterm"
export PATH='/Developer/usr/bin':$PATH
export PATH='/usr/local/bin':$PATH
```

I added the path '/Developer/usr/bin' by following a trick posted on Apple forums ([click here](https://discussions.apple.com/message/15728986#15728986)) to resolve the cvs issue on OS X Lion.

What causes the python script to identify cvs when run from command-line and not identify it when the same script is run as a compiled Mac app ?

This question is killing me. My bash and the sh both of them can find cvs when run from the terminal, but the Mac app can't. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run a OSX GUI app from Finder/Dock ie not the terminal a new shell is not started thus your .profile  is not read.

You can set environment variables in ~/.MacOS/environment.plist as per [Apple doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPRuntimeConfig/Articles/EnvironmentVars.html)

You could also set the environment (e.g. add to the path) or explicitly use the full paths to cvs and svn in the python script

Comment: However, logging out and back in will allow the new settings in .profile to be picked up..

Comment: @Mark. That's right. OSX GUI apps do not read .profile. I edited the ~/.MacOS/environment.plist file using the Property List Editor and restarted the Mac (restarting was required). Without restarting, if I tried to use the GUI app, it doesn't recognize. But, now after restarting, when I run the GUI app, it recognizes cvs and prints the expected output to the cvs_test file. Thanks a lot for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following:

```
import os
print os.environ["PATH"]
```

to your app.  I suspect it's not running with the same path as when you run your Python code from the command line.

If it turns out that your path is not what you expected, you could have your app append /usr/local/bin to the os.enviorn["PATH"]. This could be a good solution if you just need these tools for your app.

Comment: You are right. The path printed by the script is: /usr/local/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/opt/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin. But the path printed by the Mac app is: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/opt/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin. So obviously it is not using the '/Developer/usr/bin' path in it. What should I do for it to use the right path ?

Comment: I added a few lines, but it looks like you've already found a solution.